# Bug when submitting self-answered question without any tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, self-answer, instant-self-answer

Found a bug in Stack Overflow.

1. Fill out a question.
2. Tick the "Answer your own question" check box.
3. Try submitting without filling in tags.

Result:

1. System asks you for tags (correct behavior)
2. "Post Question and Answer" button disappear.
3. Answer box disappear.

Even after filling out the tags doesn't make them reappear.

Currently, the workaround is to retick the self-answer check box.

> [image: Example of bug]

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 37.0.2062.120.

Comment: it also appears that the answer field goes away too.

Comment: Anyone able to create a screenshot of this and/or update the description? I'd love to test this out too but I still had a submit button available and don't really want to create a low quality question by mistake (like many others might)

Comment: @Sayse Done. Button returns if you untick, then retick "post your own answer".

Comment: I've also tried it on another SE site (code golf) and same problem exists.

Comment: I tried it on meta.

Comment: Reproduced on Meta in Firefox 32.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm taking a look at this now and have reproduced it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this issue up. I've pushed a fix for which will be live in the next build (newer than meta: `rev 2014.9.19.2585`, q&a: `rev 2014.9.19.1875`).